# Detect when Grease Pencil object is edited

Tags: python, edit-mode, grease-pencil, draw-mode

I want the blender script to call a function when a Grease Pencil object is edited. This way, I can get the difference between the unedited and edited strokes.

This is because I want to get the **recently created stroke**. I would be thankful to know if there's an easier method of getting the recently created stroke.

Basically, something like this:

```
def grease_pencil_edited():
    #get the new stroke as a separate strokes collection
    difference = unedited_gpencil_object.strokes - edited_gpencil_object.strokes
```

Comment: It's not possible.